# phpunit dataprovider out of scope

Tags: phpunit

The class I'm testing:

```
class Calculate {
    public $x;
    public $y;

    public function __construct($x, $y) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function add(): int {
        return $this->x + $this->y;
    }
}
```

My test code:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class CalculateTest extends TestCase {

    public function additionProvider() {
        return [
            [1, 2],
            [5, 8],
            [-1, 10],
            [66, 3],
            [9, 4]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider additionProvider
     */
    public function testGetIsOk($x, $y): Calculate {
        $c = new Calculate($x, $y);
        var_dump($c);
        $this->assertEquals($x, $c->x);
        $this->assertEquals($y, $c->y);

        return $c;
    }

    /**
     * @depends testGetIsOk
     */
    public function testAddIsNormal(Calculate $c):void {
        $this->assertEquals($c->x + $c->y, $c->add());
    }



}
```

There are 5 elements in the dataprovider, but the test result shows that the 6th test is error.

> PHPUnit 6.3.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> .....E                                                              6 / 6 (100%)
>
> Time: 97 ms, Memory: 8.00MB
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) CalculateTest::testAddIsNormal
>   TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CalculateTest::testAddIsNormal() must be an inst
>       ance of Calculate, null given

Thanks.

Comment: you can check discussion on such behaviour [happened on github](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/183#issuecomment-816066)

Comment: Thank you, I finally got the answer from github, appreciate it.

Comment: A word of advice: do not let tests depend on other tests. It reduces legibility and maintenance, apart from the fact that you can't run a single test then, but end up running multiple tests.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I check the issue on github, and I finally know that I cannot pass the result of a test that get data from data providers to another test.
There is it: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/611